# I can multiple matricies in any order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to complete some fairly simple matrix algebra for a homework task.

Is it possible to multiple matrices in any order?

Is the method for the below correct?

Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for matrices $A$ and $B$,
$$AB \neq BA,$$
so we can't change the order of the *matrices* in an expression. However,
$$(AB)C=A(BC)=ABC,$$
so we can perform the *multiplication operations* in any order.

This is because we can remove all the brackets from the expression for a sequence of multiplications by repeatedly applying the rule. For example:

$$(A((BC)(DE)))F$$
$$=A((BC)(DE))F$$
$$=A(BC)(DE)F$$
$$=ABC(DE)F$$
$$=ABCDEF$$

However the terms were originally grouped, we end up with $ABCDEF$.

Comment: Do you agree that the above working is correct?

Comment: I've not checked every entry of every matrix, but the way you've gone about it is correct. You've kept the matrices in the original order and did the right operations on them. All that's missing is "=" signs between the different stages (like if you were multiplying four numbers rather than four matrices).

Comment: The main thing is that whenever you've multiplied two matrices, you've simply replaced them with the result, which is correct because it preserves the order.

Comment: great thanks!!!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar Glad to be of help!

Answer (score -1):

The algebraic explanation is that the set of $n\times n$-matrices $M_n(R)$ over a commutative ring $R$ (entries) forms a ring with unity (unit matrix). This includes that the multiplicative monoid is associative, i.e.,
$A(BC) = (AB)C$ for any matrices $A,B,C\in M_n(R)$.

Comment: Therefore is the above correct

Comment: Indeed, its correct.

Comment: thanks @Wuestenfux !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!